# to find the values

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query, gs-vlookup

I need to find out Which supplier gives the lowest price When we have more suppliers giving the same product (Barcode). I have so many suppliers and they supply the same product. in that case i need to find out who give me the lowest price without manual lookup. Mr. @Kirkg13 gave me a solution to find out the lowest price among the latest price. Now i want to display Who gives the lowest price When we enter a barcode which is common in all suppliers.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [To display which supplier gives the lowest price](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62761526/to-display-which-supplier-gives-the-lowest-price)

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(VLOOKUP(J2:J&K2:K, 
 SORT(SPLIT({A2:A&B2:B&"♦"&A1; C2:C&D2:D&"♦"&C1}, "♦"), 2, 1), 2, 0)))
```

[image]

Comment: how can we display the lowest supplier in another tab (sheet3 or sheet4 etc) ???

Comment: am really sorry. and one issue is there with your solution hope you will clear it soon. problem is if one code present only in either supplier a or supplier b lowest supplier  column wont show answer. and other one is both code have to come in one row itself for the answer. please fix it

Comment: pls tel me at which time you came online next time

Comment: pls take a look in this sheet https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1AscLCZPEv6uHJkgr2KkLJ7V_w7GfySV_19-eiQQ7Sx8/edit#gid=1464637808