# To display which supplier gives the lowest price

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-api

I have a sheet that gives the lowest price among two suppliers.  the problem is it displays the value only if both barcode comes in the same row. pls help me to expand this equation that where ever matching barcode comes in the sheet must give me the lowest supplier.supplier column ("K") works only if the same barcode comes in same row ("A" & "C") an eg is there ABC213 are not in same row, so "K" doesnt give value. i have applied a formula there. so if u can modify it that would be a great help for me

Comment: Does this answer your question? [To find the lowest supplier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62722347/to-find-the-lowest-supplier)

Comment: @JeffRush not yet friend. if u go to that sheet then u can find out that equation works only if the code comes in same row. it must work where ever the codes in the column

Comment: @AryaMurali please go the [original](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62722347/to-find-the-lowest-supplier) question and add details there. Opening the same question over and over again isn't in line with the community rules.

Answer (score 1):

To get **lowest price** you can use [MIN()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094017?hl=en), example `=MIN(B2, D2)` :
[image]

For the **K2** you already have the formula which works well

`=INDEX(A$1:D$1,match(J2,A2:D2,0)-1)`

And now you select cells J2 + K2 and just drag down to expand it.

[image]